# tr / td height refuses to be 0

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something very simple: get the height of a `tr` to `0px`, but it won't work.

See the code or [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yev1pmx0/1/) for what I've tried.

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Title 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Title 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="model">
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="delete" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
.model, .model * {
  max-height: 0 !important;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-top: 0 !important;
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.model {
  background-color: red;
}
```

RESULT:

[image: Result]

There is red in the result, so the `tr` height is still not 0.

How can I get it to be 0, *while maintaining the width*?

**EDIT**: The issue seems to be the `checkbox` nested into the `td`. How can I get *its* height down to 0?

Comment: Why do you want to make the TR in 0 height? Or just wanted to make those input fields to be hidden from the user?

Comment: @FrozenFire Why is a little hard to explain well in 600 characters, but I can say that I need the `tr` height to be 0, not just the inputs.

Comment: You can put those inputs under title 1 or 2 then hide it.

Comment: @FrozenFire Hide it by... Making the height 0? Also, they should stay as their own `tr`.

Comment: How about hiding the whole row? using `style="display:none;"`.

Comment: @FrozenFire See my edit that I need width to be preserved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101446/discussion-between-frozenfire-and-quelklef).

Answer (score 32):

I would add `visibility: collapse;` to `tr` to fix that

Comment: Avoid giving one-liner answer. Try to explain your answer, or add it as a comment when you will have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @DilshanLiyanage it might look good for you. But I am sure there are many people who would not understand the one-liner answer. So that's why here on SOF it's always recommended to explain your answer instead of just adding a one-liner solution.

Comment: @DeepakKumar yeah.. but not when its this direct

Comment: @DeepakKumar Disagree, this is exactly what is needed. If you think differently I challenge you to show us how much more detail is needed.

Comment: Since so many people upvoted this answer, its worth reading commentary in this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862431/1402498

Answer (score 10):

Add `font-size:0; margin:0;` to the class

Comment: Good answer, but I need to maintain the width. See my edit, sorry.

Comment: @Quelklef Can the solution explicitly specify any widths? If so, use the font-size:0 and manually state the widths.

Comment: While I could do this, I'd prefer not to. This way, I can change the width of the child without having to then change the properties of the `tr`.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party, but I had the same problem with a Bootstrap 3 table.  Looking in Chrome inspector, it looks like the bootstrap css selectors are very specific, so they seem to take precedence over my css unless I am even more specific.  So while the following did not work:

```
tr.my-class td {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

tr.my-class.expanded td  {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Changing it to this to mirror the Bootstrap selectors worked:

```
table>tbody>tr.my-class>td {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

table>tbody>tr.my-class.expanded>td  {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I used the search term "html smash height" in DDG. I think I understand why it took me here, now... (smash is a term used in LaTeX to erase the height attribute of an object without making the content invisible).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a `DIV`, set it to not be tall enough, hide the `overflow`:

```
div {
 height: 1.2em;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your suggestion. While it does kinda work, it doesn't set the `tr` height to 0 which is what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a very similar problem - my solution was to set both height and max-height to s.th. slightly *above* 0, like so

```
height:0.01px; max-height:0.01px;
```

perhaps combined with

```
visibility:hidden;
```

No idea, why setting it to 0 does not work. But, perhaps, using 0.01px instead of 0px ist still sufficient for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set these as well if you'd like to keep the width.

```
line-height: 0 !important;
visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of few other solutions:

```
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

if this don't have whole text and you have part if it showing up you can use:

```
<td><div>text</div></td>
```

and additionally:

```
td div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BE WARNED ABOUT PERFORMANCE ISSUES

This is truly worth calling out in its own answer because it applies to various solutions and angles on this page.

If you're trying to set a table row to zero-height, there is a reasonable chance you are working on a tabular view where you are trying to make collapsable/roll-out rows with subrows below them. If that person is you, then this post may save you pain.

I had a solution working that depended on font-size and other properties to create the impression of a table-row collapsing.  I thought it was great, until I discovered that when the table got big enough, the browser would freeze-up/lag for moments when the user tried to interact with it.

I value performance over sketchy solutions, so I ditched all of my fancy CSS transitions and slide-out effects and went for straight-up 'visibility: collapse' toggle.  I used javascript setTimeout() function to iterate subrows and make them become visible or collapsed to simulate slideout behavior.  It doesn't make a smooth slide-out effect, but it visually communicates the idea to the user and the performance is very fast and reliable.

Lesson learned:  when dealing with tables and trying to emulate closeable table rows, be warned that all the attribute adjustments required to get smooth behavior may cause you grief in the wild. Value performance and simplicity above all else.

Answer (score -2):

By using opacity we can hide the contents of `tr td` Once check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/arajajyothibabu/yev1pmx0/2/)